# How to store nil with Rails.cache.fetch & memcache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, null, memcached

I have an existing Model singleton method triggering expensive database queries that I want to model cache.  To do this, I wrapped a `Rails.cache.fetch()` call around the method in question:

```
# app/models/specialist.rb
class Specialist < ActiveRecord::Base

  def city
    Rails.cache.fetch([self.class.name, self.id, "city"], expires_in: 23.hours) do

      # expensive legacy query:
      if responded?
        o = offices.first
        return nil if o.blank?
        return o.city
      elsif hospital_or_clinic_only?
        (hospitals.map{ |h| h.city } + clinics.map{ |c| c.cities }).flatten.reject{ |i| i == nil }.uniq.first
      elsif hospital_or_clinic_referrals_only?
        (offices.map{ |o| o.city } + hospitals.map{ |h| h.city } + clinics.map{ |c| c.cities }).flatten.reject{ |c| c.blank? }.uniq.first
      else
        nil
      end

    end
  end

end
```

Executing `.city` on all records used to take 16 seconds; with this `Rails.cache.fetch` block it only dropped to 7 seconds because half the records were still triggering database calls.

When I investigated I discovered that when the `city` method returns `nil`, Rails.cache does not write the result into memcache -- meaning half my specialist records still trigger expensive database lookups despite being "cached"

How do I force `Rails.cache.fetch` to store the value of `nil` when using memcache so that another database lookup to find nil again isn't triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a NullObject, like this:

```
class Specialist
  NullData = Struct.new(nil)

  def city
    result = Rails.cache.fetch([self.class.name, self.id, "city"], expires_in: 23.hours) do
      if responded?
        ..
      else
        NullData.new()
      end
     result.is_a?(NullData) ? nil : result 
   end
end
```

That way you create a null object that can be cached. Then when you return you check if it's a null object that has been stored, in that case you return nil (to make sure you don't break your old code that relies on your method returning nil), else you return the cached content.

Comment: This sounds promising, but I can't get the syntax you've provided to work.  On Rails 3.1 with Ruby 1.9.3 I get: ```/app/models/specialist.rb:235:in `new': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+) (ArgumentError)```   I updated my answer to include the class I am working with.  Could you please adjust your answer for how I can use ```Struct``` to create a ```NullData``` object for singleton model method with the correct syntax?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Kelseydh forgot that the struct needed at least one argument. Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you.  After getting your answer working, I dropped `NullData = Struct.new(nil)` from my models.  Instead I created a `NullData` ruby class (in `lib/null_data.rb`) to allow me to call `NullData.new` anywhere.  Another gotcha:  the "legacy" query shown above uses `return` when giving back `nil` in some places.  To get this working I had to refactor the legacy query to not use `return` within the cache block, as this caused ```result.is_a?(NullData) ? nil : result ``` within the method to be skipped.

Comment: @Marcus - Thanks for the answer. 1 question - NullData.new() creates new object every time. Is there any workaround to this so that we can use a single object everytime to cache? Isnt that better?